# I am unable to add Junit Maven Dependency in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, pom.xml

I have created a Maven Java Project. And I'm doing automation testing for an iOS App. I am unable to resolve Junit related dependency issues.
My test Class is under src/test/java

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.hft.sammar</groupId>
<artifactId>AppiOSTests</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.2.0</junit.jupiter.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <release>12</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.test.MainClassName</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <!-- packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And in the console it says

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project AppiOSTests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

and few other statments like 
package org.junit does not exist
package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist and so on

Comment: I copied and pasted the POM.xml to a sample project and it build without an error.

Comment: It's not working at my end. Would be the problem?

Comment: in your maven user settings which repository you're directing to? Does the package `org.junit.jupiter.api` exist there?

Comment: where can we see maven user settings?

Comment: `MAVEN_HONE\conf\settings.xml`

Comment: I'm working on Mac. I cannot find this file.

Comment: First remove `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` and follow convention and put main code into `src/main/java` and put your tests into `src/test/java` ...furthermore show the class which has compilation errors...

Answer (score 1):

Almost all Maven issues can be solved be doing one of these:

1. `Right Click your Project` -> `Run As...` -> `Maven build...` -> Enter `dependency:resolve clean install` in "Goals" -> Click `OK`
2. `Right Click your Project` in Project Explorer -> `Maven` -> `Update Project...` -> Check `"Force Update of Snapshots/Releases"` -> Click `OK`

Answer (score 0):

Just clean the project and build it once again. Dependency version conflicts might be present in .m2/ repository.

If the problem exits after doing the above step. Delete .m2 folder and restart your workspace and build the project.

This should fix your issue.